# converting a string to Unicode in C

Tags: unicode

I have a string in a variable and that string comes from the core part of the project. Now i want to convert that to unicode string. How can i do that 
and adding L or _T() or TEXT() is not an option.
To further make thing clear please see below

```
Void foo(char* string) {
    //Here the contents of the variable STRING should be converted to Unicode
    //The soln should be possible to use in C code.
}
```

TIA 
Naveen

Comment: What platform? Or do you want a portable unicode library? And what do you mean by "unicode"? Do you mean UTF-16? What format is the string in already? If it's pure ASCII, there's nothing to do, ASCII is a subset of unicode, so if it's ASCII, it's unicode.

Comment: thanks for the lightning reply, here my actual need is, i am using SafeArrayPutElement, and for this api the 3rd parameter is a void*, in my case i want to pass string, so if i pass directly the char* string the API fails saying out of memory. but for testing purpose if i use (L"ChkIt") is works fine. so how to 'L'(convert to unicode) the contents of string variable TIA

Comment: So you want to convert narrow characters to wide characters?

Comment: well even i ve used wchar_t but the result is same(out of memory) anyway wat does 'L' do in L"string" and how to do the same for the string present in a char* vaiable

Comment: `L""` is a [wide string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#C.2FC.2B.2B) of type `wchar_t`. Does the method expect null-terminated strings and are you providing them?

Comment: [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L` is used to create wchar_t literals.

From your comment about `SafeArrayPutElement` and the way you us the term 'Unicode' it's clear you're using Windows. Assuming that that `char* string` is in the legacy encoding Windows is using and not UTF-8 or something (a safe assumption on Windows) you can get a wchar_t string in the following ways:

```
// typical Win32 conversion in C
int output_size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,string,-1,NULL,0);
wchar *wstring = malloc(output_size * sizeof(wchar_t));
int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,string,-1,wstring,output_size);
assert(output_size==size);

// make use of wstring here

free(wstring);
```

If you're using C++ you might want to make that exception safe by using std::wstring instead (this uses a tiny bit of C++11 and so may require VS2010 or above):

```
std::wstring ws(output_size,L'\0');
int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP,0,string,-1,ws.data(),ws.size());
// MultiByteToWideChar tacks on a null character to mark the end of the string, but this isn't needed when using std::wstring.
ws.resize(ws.size() -1);

// make use of ws here. You can pass a wchar_t pointer to a function by using ws.c_str()

//std::wstring handles freeing the memory so no need to clean up
```

Here's another method that uses more of the C++ standard library (and takes advantage of VS2010 not being completely standards compliant):

```
#include <locale> // for wstring_convert and codecvt

std::wstring ws = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,std::mbstate_t>,wchar_t>().from_bytes(string);

// use ws.c_str() as before
```

You also imply in the comments that you tried converting to wchar_t and got the same error. If that's the case when you try these methods for converting to wchar_t then the error lies elsewhere. Probably in the actual content of your string. Perhaps it's not properly null terminated?

Comment: Hi Bames, thanks for the answer, works perfectly... again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can't say "converted to Unicode". You need to specify an *encoding*, Unicode is not an encoding but (roughly) a character set and a set of encodings to express those characters as sequences of bytes.

Also, you must specify the input encoding, how is e.g. a character such as "å" encoded in `string`?